# android How to convert pixel coordinates to LatLng on mapsv2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've looked on the net but couldn't find an accurate answer. I have an `ImageView` to use as a marker centred on map, Its position not change when I pan the map. I want to get the latlng of position when I stop panning on the map. I guess I have to use projection but because of I am not so expert in android I got stuck. Can anybody help please.

Comment: Did you try using directly markers?

Answer (score 6):

Use ***map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(Point)*** and ***map.getProjection().toScreenLocation(LatLng)*** to convert between screen position and geo location.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Projection` via `map.getProjection()`.

This will allow you to convert between screen coordinates and `LatLng`s. The pixels returned are relative to the `View` containing the map.

Comment: where do I need to call this method? onCreate or anywhere else?

Comment: Whenever you want. The map needs to be set up. `onCreate` is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

For Maps API v2

```
VisibleRegion vr = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
double left = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.longitude;
double top = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.latitude;
double right = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.longitude;
double bottom = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.latitude;
```

Also you can use,

```
LatLngBounds curScreen = mMap.getProjection()
                .getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
```

Hope this will help.